# Understanding MTD-f

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, search-algorithms

In the **[MTD-f](http://people.csail.mit.edu/plaat/mtdf.html)** algorithm:

```
function MTDF(root : node_type; f : integer; d : integer) : integer;
    g := f;
    upperbound := +INFINITY;
    lowerbound := -INFINITY;
    repeat
        if g == lowerbound then beta := g + 1 else beta := g;
        g := AlphaBetaWithMemory(root, beta - 1, beta, d);
        if g < beta then upperbound := g else lowerbound := g;
    until lowerbound >= upperbound;
    return g;
```

Why exactly is this line: `if g == lowerbound then beta := g + 1 else beta := g` included, instead of just setting `beta := g`? Is it simply to ensure that once a lower bound is found, that the next calls to `AlphaBetaWithMemory` will return different/new results?